# How to package all required libraries with .so file linux

Tags: java, c++, linux, object, shared

I am attempting to port an application that was written with a combination of c++ for the back end, and java for the front end. This application relies on the library opencv 2.4.13, which is outdated, as well as multiple other libraries. The concern i have is that i do not want the end user to need to install these dependant programs, as they have been proving challenging to install on any but a select few linux distributions. I believe the term i am looking for is statically linking, but i'm a bit unfamiliar with c++ compilation at the moment, so i am unsure the steps i need to take to make these files portable. The java application requires these files to be libraries, and while i have managed to get them to compile on one machine, the problem seems to be getting them to run on a different one after compilation.

Comment: You're going to run into the problem that the JRE isn't statically linked to your library. And you probably can't fix that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother - this might also give you licensing problems, depending on what libraries you need.

Instead, just figure out what platforms your application is supposed to run on and package the libraries for each platform with your jar - or download them at startup, or provide them as a separate package. The exact mechanics you choose depend on your use case, the point is you don't need to rely on system wide installs.

Comment: I Would like to package the .so files with it, but i'm not exactly sure how. I don't know how to ensure that the .so will load the libraries from the local directory when i call System.load in java, so i am unsure as to how i can package the required .so files with it.